# Update with Varchar2 column with numeric values in where clause sometimes works with numeric values but sometimes gives invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's say the following is the data where A is numeric and not a primary key B is varchar2 with numeric values:

Table

[image: 1]

The following update statement works:

Update Table
Set columnA = 12340
Where ColumnB = 98761

Although B is varchar, it works without any quotes, such that '98761'.

When I try to reverse the change like this:

Update Table
Set columnA = 23450
Where ColumnB = 98761

This gives an invalid numeric error. When I encase column B in quotations like

Update Table
Set columnA = 23450
Where ColumnB = '98761'

The update works as should be since it is varchar2.

My problem is that I cannot figure out why the first case is working, without any quotes even though the value is varchar2. Since the error causing column is B, why only implicit conversion happens in one case.

Comment: Is columnb indexed? by itself or with other columns. Note that implicit conversion happens in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle implicite conversions and comparison rules are pretty complex. You can find something about it here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/423181_1.html
Probably the best approach is to make sure that you manage the data with their original types. This means that your update should look something like this:

```sql
Update Table Set columnA = '23450' Where ColumnB = '98761'
```

Relying on implicite conversions (especialy with date/datetime) depends on too many things (for me) to be sure that it will work as expected. Regards...
**Addition**
A part of the explanation from the first of the links above:
Implicit and Explicit Data Conversion
Oracle recommends that you specify explicit conversions, rather than rely on implicit or automatic conversions, for these reasons:

SQL statements are easier to understand when you use explicit datatype conversion functions.

Implicit datatype conversion can have a negative impact on performance, especially if the datatype of a column value is converted to that of a constant rather than the other way around.

**Implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs** and may not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit conversion from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an unexpected year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter.

Algorithms for implicit conversion are subject to change across software releases and among Oracle products. Behavior of explicit conversions is more predictable.

Comment: I understand the best practice. But that still doesn't explain why the first query works. Since in both first and second queries, the value I is being used without quotes, shouldn't then the values be treated similarly?

Comment: Well, that is hard to tell as it depends on database settings (versions), NLS_ settings and some other things that I don't know of. Additionaly, implicite conversions limit the use of indexes too. Sorry, but the answer is hard to tell without the insight in your database settings and all. I would also expect the same treatment of the values but there is not the same thing writing the value to the table or comparing it with something. The rules are different.

Comment: I have an update: There is a function based index on column A. When this index is disabled, the query acts consistently in both the cases i.e. both fail unless column B value is enclosed in quotes (eliminating implicit conversion). When index is rebuilt, the same problems starts i.e. giving invalid number error for one value of column A and working fine with another. The problem then is why is an index on column A affecting implicit conversion in column B.

Comment: The indexed columns involved in implicit conversions, comparisons and sortings are even more complicated story. In my opinion, arguably, that is definetly the point of no implicit conversion at all. Indexing and taking care of apropriate sorting may be a reaason for Oracle not to take the conversion at all. That would probably be the case you are facing. Quote from docs: "Oracle Database automatically converts a value from one datatype to another when such a conversion makes sense" - end quote.

Comment: And if it works on some values and not on some other then maybe there could be a problem with the data. Do you have any characters other than numbers in your data (decimal or grouping symbols or something else). One more quote: "Conversions between character values or NUMBER values and floating-point number values can be inexact, because the character types and NUMBER use decimal precision to represent the numeric value, and the floating-point numbers use binary precision" end quote.

Comment: I had such a problem some time ago with Null value in one column of one row. It was implicit conversion from varchar to number (opposite direction). After I put in a select CAST(column_with null_value as NUMBER) it was ok. Regards...

Comment: Had those problems too when fetching the data over dbLink from the database having different version and/or setup. Mostly with DATEs.